# Using same jenkins job for deployment of different applications in different servers

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins

I have six separate deployment jobs in jenkins for deploying two different applications in three different servers. Listed below are the job names.

1. deploy ProductApplication1 dev
2. deploy ProductApplication1 ppe
3. deploy productApplication1 prod
4. deploy ProductApplication2 dev
5. deploy ProductApplication2 ppe
6. deploy productApplication2 prod

In each of the jenkin job above, I could see a similar build configuration as below. As I am using jenkins for the first time I cannot really understand the shell commands written.

[image]

I would like to create a single job which could accept the environment(dev/ppe/prod) as a parameter and deploy accordingly.

What are the steps that are required to be followed for achieving this. Requesting you to explain on what changes that would be required on .yml or ansible scripts files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it can be solved with a simple parameterized build.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build for details

Then define 2 parameters for your jobs. Then replace occurrences of the values to the parameter variable (e.g. $APPLICATION and $SERVER)

For more details in the suggestion, you would have to expose the current solution in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be just one job using a multi-configuration job.
you can provide the applications and servers as axis...

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin

even you can label the servers and restrict on which slaves it has to run..